# Effects using #undefine without first defining (#define) a macro

Tags: c++, macros, googletest

I have this unnecessary code that I include in my test. This runs well, however is there an effect when you #undefine the never defined macro?

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include "header.h"
#undef protected
#undef private
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the C++ specification:

> A preprocessing directive of the form `#undef identifier new-line` causes the specified identifier no longer to be defined as a macro name. **It is ignored if the specified
>   identifier is not currently defined as a macro name.**